# dkms.conf location for new build RocketRaid documentation

Tags: compiling, raid, dkms

Noob at work here. I have Ubuntu Server 14.04.03 LTS installed and running. I added a Highpoint RocketRaid 640L internal SATA adapter. I installed 4 drives and have them configured in RAID 5 via the BIOS-based software. I'm trying to get the Ubuntu server to recognize the array. In following the instructions from the Community Help Wiki (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RocketRaid) I've trucked along just fine until the step, "5) Create dkms.conf in the root of your build...".

I'm sorry, but I'm not sure where the root of the build is.

Is it the directory rr64xl-linux-src-v1.3 that now exists off of my home directory or is it below that in product, etc.?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: When configured it presents itself to the OS like one large drive. Is at the root of this drive that you should create the file.